# MongoDb logs not showing logs for deleted records

Tags: mongodb

I lost almost 80k documents in a collection. But in mongo logs, there are no entries of those 80k documents deleted. Is there any other ways to find out how the records were deleted? I have a backup, so I know precisely which records were deleted.
 Logs were retrieved from the server and by using `getLog` command

Comment: getLog returns mongod events, not queries https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/index.html. You may find some traces in oplog if it happened recently, or in system.profile if the write was slow enough.

Comment: did not find anything in oplog as well :(

Comment: oplog is capped, you had to do it asap. You can find a timestamp of the oldest record there. If it is earlier than your last backup than the query is definitely there. Otherwise there are chances the log entry was overwritten by more recent updates. Just to make it crystal clear it could be a single update that deleted all 80k documents, not necessarily 80k updates.

Comment: There is no way a single query could those records, Also in system there is no other way to delete more than 50 records in a single query. oplog was overwritten :( I think then there is no way to get the log now

Comment: `db.collection.remove({})` can delete all documents and I don't see a way to limit it to "no more than 50" to be honest. There is a tiny chance the query (or one of the queries) took more than 100ms and were recorded to slowlog, but generally speaking yes, since the oplog was overwritten, you are out of luck.

Comment: we have written a code which restricts any remove query from code and server access is restricted as well. yeah but still there are ways to fire the query for developers.. I restored the backup so that's taken care of. Anyway if you want you can put your first comment as answer.